# Trying to implement interface and override java.lang.String with Byte Buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy, javaagents

I tried with [this example](https://github.com/ShehanPerera/javaagent-bytebuddy/tree/master/samples/ignore-class) especially designed for
ignored by byte-buddy.

I solved errors, and it looks like working with this code.

```java
new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
      .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
      .type((ElementMatchers.named("String")))
      .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
        .implement(AutoCloseable.class)
        .method(named("close"))
        .intercept(Advice.to(closeInterceptor.class))
      ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

and my interceptor looks like this.
I did `System.out.print` something in the interceptor,
but nothing happens over time.
(FYI, my logger setting was bad and caused an error. I deleted logger things and just used `System.out.println`

```java
class closeInterceptor {

  public void intercept(@Origin Class<?> type) {
    try {
      Field field = type.getDeclaredField("value");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Object ref = field.get(null);
      // I'm trying to deal with `java.lang.String`s internal character storage.
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to confirm that it's working well?

Thanks in advance.
(I forgot to say `Happy new year!`)

---

The default example looks like it is working at first, but look at this log.

Disconnected with this error `Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099`

I changed the port number randomly, but no effect and the same error occurred.

Please help!

```java
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49960', transport: 'socket'
Agent for instrument ignored class like java class 
method private static void sun.management.Agent.readConfiguration(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)
method public static java.util.Properties sun.management.Agent.loadManagementProperties()
.
.
.
method public static final long java.util.zip.ZipUtils.get32(byte[],int)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49960', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from server
```

---

Here is the log.

```java
Agent for instrument ignored class like java class 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [] allows for delegation from public abstract void java.lang.AutoCloseable.close() throws java.lang.Exception
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$Processor.bind(MethodDelegationBinder.java:1026)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$Appender.apply(MethodDelegation.java:1051)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:620)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:609)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:526)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining$RedefinitionClassVisitor.visitEnd(TypeWriter.java:3865)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:702)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:2941)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1633)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:171)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:92)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:2639)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2741)
    at com.github.shehanperera.ignored.Agent.premain(Agent.java:43)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49960', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from server
```

Here is My `premain`.

```java
public static void premain(String arguments,
  Instrumentation instrumentation) {

  System.out.println("Agent for instrument ignored class like java class ");

  ByteBuddyAgent.install();
  new ByteBuddy()
    .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
    .redefine(String.class)
    .ignoreAlso(ElementMatchers.none())
    .implement(AutoCloseable.class)
    .method(named("close"))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(closeInterceptor.class))
    .make()
    .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
    .getLoaded();


  new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
    .ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
    .type((ElementMatchers.any()))
    .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
      .method(ElementMatchers.any())
      .intercept(Advice.to(IgnoreClass.class))
    ).installOn(instrumentation);

}
```

And finally, my interceptor.

```java
class closeInterceptor {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(closeInterceptor.class);
  public void intercept(@Origin Class<?> type) {
    try {
      Field field = type.getDeclaredField("value");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Object ref = field.get(null);
      // I'm trying to deal with `java.lang.String`s internal character storage.
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know about byte code manipulation well also byte buddy.

It's hard to find some reference...

Please help.

I just tried to make `Java.lang.String` implements `AutoCloseable`
and `Override` the `close` method with `java agent` and `byte buddy`.

I hope so it can be.

But I can't solve that error and exception.

Comment: Are you trying to hack a way for `String[]` to implement `close()` method? The error complains about a missing implementation of that method by []. Or i terribly misunderstood what went wrong there...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. @Shark I want to hack `java.lang.String` and implement the` close()` method. That's right. For now, I have no errors, but I can't confirm that working correctly or not.

Comment: Instrumentation can't add methods, so my guess is: no, it can't work.

Comment: The only way to do this for JRE bootstrap classes which are already loaded when you are trying to instrument them, is to instrument them separately, write the instrumented classes to disk and put them on the boot classpath, prepending the woven ones, so the JVM finds them first. The exact way to do that is different between JRE <= 8 and 9+.

Comment: Let’s pretend the Instrumentation worked. What is `field.get(null)` with a non-static field supposed to do? And what code shall invoke the `close()` method (that only exists after the Instrumentation added it) eventually? So letting aside that you can’t instrument `String` that way, it looks like the actual problems would just start when the Instrumentation would work…

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you would need to specify `java.lang.String` as name, not just `String`.

However, it is not possible to change the shape of classes that are already loaded. Therefore, you are not able to add an interface to a class like String which will always be loaded upon agent startup with Byte Buddy.